# Complexity of Algorithm: log(x^2 + x^3) = O(?)

Tags: complexity-theory, big-o, logarithm

While I understand the concept of both complexity of algorithms and logarithmic complexity in programming, I do not know how to determine the complexity of a logarithm that includes variables of different powers.

Here are some examples:

```
log(x^2 + 3x^3) = O(?)

log(x^3 + 5) = O(?)
```

Any help would be very appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
O(log(x))
```

Just because of the mathematical rule that `log(xk) = k⋅log(x)` (that's strictly from the definition of log)

Also, we know that O is an asymptotic multiplicative notation, so multiplying by a constant does not affect it.

**Proof:**

`log(x² + 3x³) ≤ log(4x³) ≤ log(x⁴)`  for big enough x

So `log(x²+3x³) ≤ log(4x³) ≤ log(x⁴) = 4⋅log(x)` which we know is O(log(x)) by definition

This is proof of the upper O bound

On the other direction (Showing Theta which isn't needed but you might be interested in)

`log(x²+3x³) ≥ log(x²) >= 2⋅log(x)` which is O(log(x)) by definition